# Try a set of passwords on (.zip/.rar) to decompress a file using .bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am running this code. It works fine, only with the problem that, if the actual password is not in the first line (ex-www.top2download.com) winRAR gives an error saying- "Password incorrect or file is broken" . I have to close that 'Error Dialog Box' to keep the codes running. How ever once it reaches to the actual password it extracts and exits immediately :) . What I want is, to block the 'error dialog box' from appearing . or, do not try to extract if the error code is greater than 1, in any line.

Extra Info: %result% is the output of "BrowseFiles" i.e,the file I want to extract. I want the job to be done by "WinRAR.exe" (not "unRAR.exe").

```
@echo off
echo.------------------------------------------------
echo Choose the file, you want to extract:
echo.------------------------------------------------
rem BrowseFiles
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" x -pfile.ge %result%
if %ERRORLEVEL% GEQ 1 GOTO continue1
if %ERRORLEVEL% GEQ 0 GOTO exit
:continue1
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" x -pwww.top2download.com %result%
if %ERRORLEVEL% GEQ 1 GOTO continue2
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 GOTO exit
:continue2
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" x -pworldfree4u.com %result%
GOTO exit
:exit
exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves the answer you added - `&&` will execute `goto :EOF` when errorlevel is 0 otherwise it will continue with the next line.

```
@echo off
echo.------------------------------------------------
echo Choose the file, you want to extract:
echo.------------------------------------------------
rem BrowseFiles
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" x -inul -pfile.ge %result% && goto :EOF
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" x -inul -pwww.top2download.com %result% && goto :EOF
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" x -inul -pworldfree4u.com %result% && goto :EOF
```

Comment: Yah! but it will only make my program short. WinRar still attempts the file to extract with a wrong password. Is there any way that winrar will skip the lines with wrong passwords and only execute the line with the right password in it?

Comment: If you know the right password then you can apply that one - otherwise the code can't tell which password is right without trying it.  The code above will try every password and exit after it finds the right one, according to the errorlevel.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution..
    "C:\Program Files\WinRAR
\WinRAR.exe" x -inul -
pwww.file.ge %result%   .
Do not show any error box.. as -inul disables diagnostic messages of winRAR. But, can I make the trick, such that if error code i.e,
    %ERRORLEVEL% 
is greater than 1 the corresponding commands will not be executed..